# preventing CSS transition to font-size 0 from Jumping

Tags: css, css-transitions

I want to have a division disappear by shrinking smoothly.
I tried doing this by making the font-size change to 0 with transition set to 1s.

When I do this the font gets some some minimum size, then freezes and then disappears causing a jerky jumpy change to the layout.

I would like it to shrink smoothly like it does when `transform:scale(0)` is set, but the layout doesn't change when I do this.

Here is a jsFilddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/3e0ajpzL/1/

**css**

```
.shown {
  font-size: 2em;
  transition: 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
Top
<div onclick=hide(this) id=target class=shown>
  Click to make me go away<br>
  -----------------<br>
  more lines<br>
  make <br>
  it <br>
  Worse
</div>
<div style=cursor:pointer onclick=restore()>
  Click to bring him back
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function hide(ele) {
  ele.classList.toggle("hidden");
}

function restore() {
  document.getElementById("target").classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

**EDIT**
This appears to not happen on the edge browser.  I am using chrome browser.

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem. I've put the transition time up to 10s too to get a better look. It's jerky, but consistently so. This is on Windows10/Edge. What OS/browser are you using?

Comment: I am running this on chrome.  It works like I expect on edge, so that makes sense why you are confused.

Comment: Have you got a minimum font size set in Chrome?

Comment: It's pretty smooth for me on Chrome and Firefox (Windows).

Comment: @AHaworth Thats it!  I have no idea why that was set.

Comment: There was a time (I don't know about nowadays) that Chrome didn't like font size going below 12px I think, Do you want to put the 'solution' into an answer and accept it so future readers can find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `A Haworth` pointed out, in some browsers you can set a minimum font size.  I appear to have done this on my chrome browser.  On the current chrome browser you can get to this setting by going to setting>appearance>custom fonts or by going to chrome://settings/fonts

Set the minimum font size to the lowest setting to the lowest setting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `line-height`

```
.shown {
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 1em;
    transition: 1s all;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hidden {
   font-size: 0;
   line-height: 0;
}
```